# Router param as string with angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want the following url:

```
user/felicia.christensen
```

And in my template, I use this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user', user.userName | lowercase]">{{user.name}}</a>
```

Here, user.userName return felicia.christensen, and it work, i get the url above.

Into my routing file, I have this:

```
{
    path: "user/:user", 
    component: UserDetailComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    data: {
        title: 'Details Of users'
    }
}
```

**My problem is:** if I reload the page, it get the following error:

```
Cannot GET /user/felicia.christensen
```

Is there anybody here, that met the same problem?
Why if I reload the page, I get the error above?

**NB:** If I use `id` of the user as paramater, it works perfectly, but I want `string` param instead of `id`

Comment: It might be caused by the `.` in the string. Can you try without it? There might already be an open issue about it. What router version are you using?

Comment: Thank you! It works, I use 3.0.0-rc.1.
Can you change your comment into answer, and I vote it?
My question, if I want to use `.` as separator, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open issue about `.` in routes

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8249

Until this is fixed, encode your value in a way that it doesn't contain a `.` or just remove it, then it should work.